# Redirect non-www and non-https to https://www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, apache2

I want to redirect non-www and non-https URLs to `https://www` for my domain, I actually have the following htaccess, that works ok redirecting non-https to https but still allows to access `domain.com` without www,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}%{QUERY_STRING} [L,R]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I've found I should use the following to force www, but I can't get where it should be placed for best, thanks

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# Remove Trailing Slashes...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L,NE]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: thanks @anubhava, why did you remove '%{QUERY_STRING}' from RewriteRule?

Comment: `%{QUERY_STRING}` isn't needed as QUERY_STRING already carries over to target.