# WP https redirect causes loop error

Tags: wordpress, redirect, https, no-www, cloudways

My Wordpress site's URL is set to HTTPS in the WP settings. If you type domain.com, it redirects to www.domain.com. If you click on the logo, it'll take you to https:/www.domain.com. I'd like https to be enabled by default on all pages.

I tried using this as Brandozz recommended and it turns out my caching plugin as well but it keeps causing the loop error.

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
 RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

My server used Nginx. The caching plugin is recommending adding a few lines of code but I'm not sure where or how. See http://docs.wp-rocket.me/article/36-fix-for-ssl-redirection-issue.. Cloudways is my host and I'm on a DigitalOcean server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect non-www and non-https to https://www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22895260/redirect-non-www-and-non-https-to-https-www)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I'm currently using to redirect everything to https

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. Are you using this for a Wordpress site? If so, do you have the wordpress url set to https as well? I experienced a loop error a few weeks back and I had to delete my htaccess which solved the problem. Then, I put back my old htaccess and it's still working fine. Not sure what the problem was but I'm hoping it doesn't cause any more issues. edit: typo

Comment: Just tried it.. It caused the site not to load.. redirect loop it said.

Comment: Yes, this is a WordPress site and in my settings the url is set to https.

Comment: That's great to know. My caching plugin must be causing the issues then. I've had nothing but trouble since I got it but my site is faster than before so I kept it. I'm using WP Rocket.

Comment: I've never used WP Rocket but it looks like a well supported plugin. Maybe you can reach out to them for support. Did disabling the plugin fix the redirect loop issue?

Comment: Yes, it's a great plugin and their support is just as good but the time difference and language barrier makes it a bit hard to get things done. I didn't have to disable the plugin, deleting the htaccess file gets the site back up. Then I reupload a copy of the htaccess and it keeps working fine until I try to add the redirection code. This isn't my first attempt at trying to resolve this issue. I did reach out to my host (totally useless support), MaxCDN, my cdn provider(can't thank them enough - they go above and beyond their duties), and cache plugin devs and that led me nowhere.

Comment: The odd thing is that I already have a non-www to http www redirect code that I had displayed in my OP above (but took it out in an edit like a fool).. I was deleting my existing redirect code and replacing it with what you recommended or with other codes that I found and they all end up with the same loop error msg. I got a headache again from this bs. Time to sleep on it for a while (again). Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]