# .htaccess redirect non-www and non-http to https://www

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to redirect:

- `http://example.extension`
- `https://example.extension`
- `http://www.example.extension`

to

- `https://www.example.extension`

using:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.extension$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^example.extension$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.extension$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.extension$1 [R=301,L]
```

`http://example.extension` is redirected to `https://www.example.extension`, however, I receive the error:

> The page isn’t redirecting properly

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22895457/667903), if I change my `.htaccess` rules to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.extension%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

the same symptom occurs, even after clearing the browser cache.

Also, I have some sub-domains I don't want to redirect to www, like:

- https://my.example.extension
- https://forum.example.extension

I need `http://*.example.extension` redirected to `https://*.example.extension`

Other than the rewrite rules I am requesting help with, the only other content in `.htaccess` is Wordpress related:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress

# BEGIN MainWP
# END MainWP
```

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CloudFlare, You must use CloudFlare Page Rules:
https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170536-How-do-I-redirect-all-visitors-to-HTTPS-SSL-

But you can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

#main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(example\.extension)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

#sub-domains
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Hi Croises. Do these rules take into account the sub-domains I have? I have added these rules, replacing the existing rules, and Firefox says: `Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete`.

I have added a Cloudflare Page Rule setting `http://*.example.extension/*` to always use `https`, and I think this works fine.

Comment: I edited my code with your subdomain question change.

Comment: You can do all the job with CloudFlare rules, but avoid to redirect after the CloudFlare proxy to the wrong domain

Answer (score 2):

There is no variable called `HTTPS_HOST`.

Replace your rule with this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

# main domain: add www and turn on https in same rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(example\.extension)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# sub domain
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache completely.

Comment: Thanks. I've replaced the `.htaccess` rules with yours above, and the same symptom occurs, even after clearing the browser and CDN (Cloud Flare) cache.

Comment: I forgot to add I have some sub-domains that need to be redirected from `http` to `https` to (i.e. I need `http://*.example.extension` redirected to `https://*.example.extension` also).

Comment: This rule is from a live website and it is working. I am adding a separate rule for subdomains but first test for main domain and make sure there is no other rule while testing this.